# Activity Transition between two RecyclerViews

Tags: android, transition, android-transitions

I animate from one `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayout` to another one. It displays images like a gallery.

The parent `RecyclerView` shows the first 3 elements of a folder, the child `RecyclerView` shows the complete content in a Grid...

**main adapter**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FolderViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.transitionPairs.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        ImageView iv = holder.getIconView(i);
        Image image = mItems.get(position).getImages().get(i);
        holder.transitionPairs.add(new Pair(iv, image.getTransitionName()));
    }
```

**child adapter**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(holder.icon, mItems.get(position).getTransitionName());
}
```

- both adapters set the SAME transition name, it's generated from the image uri, so it's surely unique

I start the child view like following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ImagesActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("folderIndex", pos);
        intent.putExtra("folder", item);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), vh.getTransitionPairs().toArray(new Pair[vh.getTransitionPairs().size()]));
            getActivity().startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
        }
       else
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

The transition pairs are saved in the `ViewHolder` and are generated whenever the `ViewHolder` is bound, as you can see in the `ViewHolders` code above

**PROBLEM**

Showing the child view is not animated, going back is animated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sorry, but that's a documented limitation of the transition framework.

https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/transitions/overview.html#Limitations

> Limitations
>
> This section lists some known limitations of the transitions framework:
>   - Classes that extend AdapterView, such as ListView, manage their child views in ways that are incompatible with the transitions framework. If you try to animate a view based on AdapterView, the device display may hang.

I know it states `ListView` but is the same for RecyclerView. The Animation framework must capture the `transitionName` value as soon as the views are laid out, and the `ListView` and `RecyclerView` take extra time to get an adapter, create the child views, laid out those child views on the screen and then have them bound to the data. The transition framework can't "see" those views.

My best suggestion for you is to have a "fake" item from your adapter inflated on the actual activity laid out, just for the transition to run onto, and then onStart you set this view go `GONE`.

**edit:**

based on the link supplied by the OP ([Having issues using Android 5.0 Activity transitions onto an activity with a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27531218/)) I've ended developing my own, but very similar solution.

On my own project I have a GridLayoutManager with about 7 elements per screen and animates to a LinearLayoutManager with mostly 1 per view (but sometimes you can see corners of the one before or after).

In the linked response the solution is to use `Activity.postponeEnterTransition()` and `Activity.startPostponedEnterTransition()` and `OnPreDrawListener` to proper deliver all the transition.

The important fact to remember is that the view must be attached to the window for the transition framework to capture it. So I used the `OnAttachStateChangeListener` to dispatch the transition, instead of `OnPreDraw`. That should make it to a subtly smooth transition.

```
// somewhere on the `onBind` code I put that
itemView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(listener);

// and this is the listener
private final View.OnAttachStateChangeListener listener = new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
         @Override public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
            activity.startPostponedEnterTransition();
            v.removeOnAttachStateChangeListener(this);
         }

         @Override public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
            v.removeOnAttachStateChangeListener(this);
         }
      };
```

it's working fine for me.

Comment: didn't know that. thanks for the information. Actually, I will stick to only animate the back transition and just forget about the display animation in this case for now... I don't want to build the first views on the detail view twice, although that's not too much work... Currently it's jsut a small beauty bug I can life with if it's not supported

Comment: just one thing, this should also be valid for a viewpager, shouldn't it?

Comment: I've never tested, but I'm pretty sure ViewPager would have the same issue

Comment: actually, I just found a way to postpone the transitions... this makes using viewpager and RecyclerViews possible as well

Comment: Would you share the answer?!?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27531218/having-issues-using-android-5-0-activity-transitions-onto-an-activity-with-a-vie this thread shows how it works... although for me, with the recyclerview, it does not work perfectly currently because I'm using the recyclerview in a coordinator layout...

Comment: that looks interesting. Tomorrow, back in the office, I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: it's working for me... although only, if I postpone the `supportStartPostponedEnterTransition` a little bit... otherwise, in my case, the recyclerview seems to not know about the EXTENDED state of the toolbar in my `CoordinatorLayout`...

Comment: please let me know if you get it working perfectly... I have a grid thats showing about 20 elements in the detail view and it seems like recycling of views makes some problems... The first 3 items are animating correctly but sometimes some other views do animate as well. Clearing the transition name in `onRecycleView` did not solve the problem... it seems like animations are started before the `onBindViewHolder` is called

Comment: I've added the code I came up with, in case u want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Make sure your RecyclerView has the proper view(s) inflated

2 - Add a SharedElementCallback using setEnterSharedElementCallback and override "onMapSharedElements".

3 - Add the missing views to the sharedElements map (get them from your adapter or RecyclerView directly).

```
    setEnterSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapSharedElements(List<String> names, Map<String, View> sharedElements) {
            sharedElements.put("bla", recyclerView.findViewWithTag("bla"));
            super.onMapSharedElements(names, sharedElements);
        }
    });
```